# Lua pattern <li> html tags

Tags: html, lua, lua-patterns

I want to extract the values within li elements and store them into variables.

Example:

```
<li>Male</li><li>Hustisford, WI</li><li>United States</li>
```

However, it could also be like this:

```
<li>Hustisford, WI</li><li>United States</li>
```

or no

I started with this:

```
author_origin = string.gsub(string.gsub(htmlcode,"<li>","#"),"</li>","|")

author_gender, author_orig_city, author_orig_country = string.match(author_origin,"#(.-)|#(.-)|#(.-)|")
```

=> this worked for the first example but not for the other cases.

I thought it should be something like this but it didn't work:

```
author_gender, author_orig_city, author_orig_country = string.match(author_origin,"[#]?(.-?)[|]?[#]?(.-?)[|]?[#]?(.-?)[|]?")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid needing multiple patterns by simply grabbing everything that matches your criteria and then figuring out what you have at the end. Something like this.

```
function extract(s)
    local t = {}
    for v in s:gmatch("<li>(.-)</li>") do
        t[#t + 1] = v
    end

    if #t == 3 then
        return (unpack or table.unpack)(t)
    end

    return nil,(unpack or table.unpack)(t)
end

author_gender, author_orig_city, author_orig_country = extract("<li>Male</li><li>Hustisford, WI</li><li>United States</li>")
print(author_gender, author_orig_city, author_orig_country)
author_gender, author_orig_city, author_orig_country = extract('<li>Hustisford, WI</li><li>United States</li>')
print(author_gender, author_orig_city, author_orig_country)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with a single patten. You need two. First try for three fields. If it fails, try for two fields. And you don't need to replace the HTML tags with others characters.

```
author_gender, author_orig_city, author_orig_country = string.match(author_origin,"<li>(.-)</li><li>(.-)</li><li>(.-)</li>")
if author_gender==nil then
   author_orig_city, author_orig_country = string.match(author_origin,"<li>(.-)</li><li>(.-)</li>")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse unpredictable HTML and don't mind depending on a library, you could use [lua-gumbo](https://github.com/craigbarnes/lua-gumbo):

```
local gumbo = require "gumbo"
local input = "<li>Male</li><li>Hustisford, WI</li><li>United States</li>"
local document = gumbo.parse(input)

local elements = document:getElementsByTagName("li")
local gender = elements[1].textContent
local city = elements[2].textContent
local country = elements[3].textContent

print(gender, city, country)
```